# How to specify XPath when two nearly equal elements are present?

Tags: xml, xpath

Please see the below snippet extracted from an XML file of a WSO2 server

```
    <Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

    <Service className="org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.service.ExtendedStandardService" name="Catalina">

        <!--
        optional attributes:

        proxyPort="80"
        -->
        <Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                   port="9763"
                   redirectPort="9443"
                   bindOnInit="false"
                   maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
                   acceptorThreadCount="2"
                   maxThreads="250"
                   minSpareThreads="50"
                   disableUploadTimeout="false"
                   connectionUploadTimeout="120000"
                   maxKeepAliveRequests="200"
                   acceptCount="200"
                   server="WSO2 Carbon Server"
                   compression="on"
                   compressionMinSize="2048"
                   noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
                   compressableMimeType="text/html,text/javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript,application/xml,text/css,application/xslt+xml,text/xsl,image/gif,image/jpg,image/jpeg"
                   URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>

        <!--
        optional attributes:

        proxyPort="443"
        Added sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" for poodle vulnerability fix
        -->
        <Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                   port="9443"
                   bindOnInit="false"
                   sslProtocol="TLS"
                   sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
                   maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
                   acceptorThreadCount="2"
                   maxThreads="250"
                   minSpareThreads="50"
                   disableUploadTimeout="false"
                   enableLookups="false"
                   connectionUploadTimeout="120000"
                   maxKeepAliveRequests="200"
                   acceptCount="200"
                   server="WSO2 Carbon Server"
                   clientAuth="want"
                   compression="on"
                   scheme="https"
                   secure="true"
                   SSLEnabled="true"
                   compressionMinSize="2048"
                   noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
                   compressableMimeType="text/html,text/javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript,application/xml,text/css,application/xslt+xml,text/xsl,image/gif,image/jpg,image/jpeg"
                   keystoreFile="${carbon.home}/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks"
                   keystorePass="wso2carbon"
                   URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
.
.
.
```

I am planning to change the **maxThreads** attribute value of the `Connector` element having the `port` attribute value as `9763`. How do I specify the extract XPath value for the above attribute?
Does the below XPath correct?

`xpath: "Server/Service/Connector[@port=\"9763\"]/maxThreads"`

(Note: There exists an another `Connector` element with some what same attributes)

Comment: If there is another `Connector` element with `port` attribute equal to `9763`, how would you choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below xpath.

```
'/Server/Service//Connector[@port="9763"]/@maxThreads'
```

OR

```
 "//Connector[@port=\"9763\"]/@maxThreads"
```